# How to change font color in a loadedHtml text

Tags: html, objective-c, xcode

I have save a string like this..

```
NSString *loadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><body><font color=\"white\">%@</font></body></html>", string];
```

Now i want to load this string in a webview using

```
[webView loadHTMLString:loadString baseURL:nil];
```

now when the webpage is loaded the colour is default as black. I want to change the colour to white but m unable to do so. any suggestion how can i change the font colour.Thanks.

EDIT 1:
I tried this but no luck..

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><style type=\"text/css\"><!--.style1 { font-family: Arial;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;}--> <body><font class=\"style1\">%@</font></body></html>", string];
```

also this..

```
NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html> \n""<head> \n""<style type=\"text/css\"> \n""body {font-family: \"%@\"; font-size: %@; color:#FFFFFF; }\n""</style> \n""</head> \n""<body>%@</body> \n""</html>", @"helvetica", [NSNumber numberWithInt:15], string];
```

Comment: I'm not answering because I don't know the answer but it could be that the `webView` isn't parsing this as html. If it was, the text should be white, unless the `webView` doesn't support the font tag.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a full listing. Just create a view controller + NIB called "WebViewTestViewController" and add the webView in your nib file and connect it.

WebViewTestViewController.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface WebViewTestViewController : UIViewController {
    UIWebView *webView;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

WebViewTestViewController.m:

```
#import "WebViewTestViewController.h"

@implementation WebViewTestViewController
@synthesize webView;

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    NSString *string = @"Hello world";
    NSString *loadString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<html><head><style>body {background:blue} p {color:white;}</style></head><body><p>%@<p></body></html>", string];
    [webView loadHTMLString:loadString baseURL:nil];

    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

- (void)dealloc {
    [webView release];
    [super dealloc];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setWebView:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}

@end
```

Comment: @Nothan If the above doesn't work this is re-enforcing my theory that the webView isn't parsing the string as html. Try adding an element like an `<input>` that can't be displayed as plain text. If the text is parsed as html this should be rendered correctly.

Comment: Thanks but no luck on my side.. dont know whats the problem. m seeing only black colour in text.
maybe MrMisterMan is right..

Comment: It works fine for me. Check out my updated answer for a full listing.

Answer (score 5):

I hope you are asking on changing the font color of the loaded files in UIWebview,You can use the following steps to change the color,size and type of the loaded content in the UIWebview,

```
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.color =\"Green\""];


[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontFamily =\"Courier New\""];
[web stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.fontSize =\"20\""];
```

here i used the javascript to change the font family,size and color of the body of the html page referenced to my outlet `IBOutlet UIWebView *web;`

Answer (score 1):

Before the body tag put this:

```
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style1 {
font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: #FFFFFF;
font-size: 20px;
font-weight: bold;
}
-->
```

And then in your font tag include:

```
 <font class="style1">
```

If this doesn't work change font for span.

EDIT ---
Here is an example...

```
<html><style type="text/css">.style1 {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;color: #FFFFFF;font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;}</style><body><span class="style1">%@</span></body></html>", string];
```

Comment: PLease check my edits. i tried ur code but no luck. please see m i writing correctly.

Comment: Thanks but no luck on my side.. dont know whats the problem. m seeing only black colour in text.